How can I make the jqplot Bubblechart is zoomed by using cursor:{zoom:true} then show drawMid as position fixed
In the below Jqplot bubble chart, the cursor can be used as zoom the bubble, here when the xMeasure.ShowMidLine & yMeasure.ShowMidLine are true the function is written like when we zoom the bubble the xMeasure.ShowMidLine (verticalLine) & yMeasure.ShowMidLine (horizontalLine) will show completely I wanted to show only the zoomed part not complete  verticalLine & horizontalLine.
Example: When jqplot is having 4 quadrants with verticalLine & horizontalLine each quadrants is having bubble when I use the cursor to zoom the left upper bubble it should show only right verticalLine & down horizontalLine not complete verticalLine & horizontalLine currently it's showing new four quadrants with verticalLine & horizontalLine where ever it's zoomed.
Before zoom:
enter image description here
After zoom:
enter image description here
I want to show the proper quadrant where exactly bubble lies in which quadrants after zooming also.
Code:
_render: function () {
                var self = this;
                var options = self.rOptions;
                var bco = options.BubblechartOptions;
                var measures = options.Measures;
                var meta = self.state.meta;
                var data = self.state.data;
                var xMeasure = _.findWhere(measures, { "RenderOn": "X" });
                var yMeasure = _.findWhere(measures, { "RenderOn": "Y" });
                var sizeMeasure = _.findWhere(measures, { "RenderOn": "Size" });
                var SERIES_COLORS = colorconfig.getMeasureColors();

                if (!meta || (sizeMeasure && meta.length < 4)) {
                    showMessage(util.getTranslatedString(util.translations.BCMNeedThreeMeasure), self.element, util.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR);
                    return;
                }

                var xMeta, yMeta, sizeMeta;
                _.each(meta, function(aMetaItem, i) {
                    aMetaItem.MetaIndex = i;
                    if (aMetaItem.MeasureId == xMeasure.Id || aMetaItem.Name == xMeasure.Name) {
                        xMeta = aMetaItem;
                    }
                    if (aMetaItem.MeasureId == yMeasure.Id || aMetaItem.Name == yMeasure.Name) {
                        yMeta = aMetaItem;
                    }
                    if (sizeMeasure && (aMetaItem.MeasureId == sizeMeasure.Id || aMetaItem.Name == sizeMeasure.Name)) {
                        sizeMeta = aMetaItem;
                    } 
                });
                     
                var xFormats = self._getFormats(xMeasure.Format, xMeta.ConversionFormatString);
                var yFormats = self._getFormats(yMeasure.Format, yMeta.ConversionFormatString);

                var divId = "o9bubblechart-" + self.widgetInstanceUniqueId;

                //Set the plot height before render
                var currentPlotHeight = self.element.height() - PLOT_OFFSET;
                self.element.find('#' + divId).height(currentPlotHeight);

                // parse and prepare the data and render
                if (data && data.length > 0 && meta && meta.length > 0) {
                    bco.xLabel = xMeasure.IsTransient ? xMeasure.Name : (xMeta.Translation || xMeasure.Name); 
                    bco.yLabel = yMeasure.IsTransient ? yMeasure.Name : (yMeta.Translation || yMeasure.Name);
                    bco.sizeLabel = (sizeMeasure) ? (sizeMeasure.IsTransient ? sizeMeasure.Name : (sizeMeta.Translation || sizeMeasure.Name)): "";

                    clearError(self.element);
                    var xAxisConfig = {
                        padMax: 1.0,
                        padMin: 1.0,
                        label: bco.xLabel,
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            showLabel: true,
                            showGridline: xMeasure.ShowGridLines,
                            formatter: function (format, value) {
                                var numeralFmt = ((value < 0) ? xFormats.n : xFormats.p);
                                return numeral(value).format(numeralFmt);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    var xMin = xMeasure.Min;
                    var xMax = xMeasure.Max;
                    var xTickCount = xMeasure.TickCount;
                    var xMinConfigured = false;
                    var xMaxConfigured = false;

                    if (xMin !== undefined && xMin !== null && isNumber(xMin)) {
                        xAxisConfig.min = +xMin;
                        xMinConfigured = true;
                    }
                    if (xMax !== undefined && xMax !== null && isNumber(xMax)) {
                        xAxisConfig.max = +xMax;
                        xMaxConfigured = true;
                    }
                    if (xTickCount && isNumber(xTickCount) && xTickCount > 1) {
                        xAxisConfig.numberTicks = +xTickCount;
                    }

                    var yAxisConfig = {
                        padMax: 1.2,
                        padMin: 1.0,
                        label: bco.yLabel,
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            showLabel: true,
                            showGridline: yMeasure.ShowGridLines,
                            formatter: function (format, value) {
                                var numeralFmt = ((value < 0) ? yFormats.n : yFormats.p);
                                return numeral(value).format(numeralFmt);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    var yMin = yMeasure.Min;
                    var yMax = yMeasure.Max;
                    var yTickCount = yMeasure.TickCount;
                    var yMinConfigured = false;
                    var yMaxConfigured = false;

                    if (yMin !== undefined && yMin !== null && isNumber(yMin)) {
                        yAxisConfig.min = +yMin;
                        yMinConfigured = true;
                    }
                    if (yMax !== undefined && yMax !== null && isNumber(yMax)) {
                        yAxisConfig.max = +yMax;
                        yMaxConfigured = true;
                    }
                    if (yTickCount && isNumber(yTickCount) && yTickCount > 1) {
                        yAxisConfig.numberTicks = +yTickCount;
                    }

                    var canvasOverlayOptions = self._getCanvasOverlayOptions(xMeasure, yMeasure);

                    var bubbleScaleFactor = bco.ScaleFactor > 0 ? bco.ScaleFactor : 1;
                    var minSize =  sizeMeasure ? sizeMeasure.MinSize : null;
                    var dataForJq = [];
                    self.state.indexVsMetaIndex = {};
                    var seriesBackgroundColors = [];
                    var seriesForegroundColors = [];
                    var colorIndex = 0;

                    _.each(data, function (aRow, i) {
                        var m1 = aRow[xMeta.MetaIndex][0];
                        var m2 = aRow[yMeta.MetaIndex][0];

                        var m3 = (sizeMeasure) ? aRow[sizeMeta.MetaIndex][0] : 10;                        

                        //Add minSize if configured
                        if (minSize && isNumber(minSize) && minSize > 0 && m3 > 0) {
                            m3 += minSize;
                        }                            

                        var label = meta[0].DimensionValues[aRow[0]].DisplayName;

                        // skip null data
                        if (m1 == null || m2 == null || m3 == null)
                            return;

                        // Check that the data is withing the configured ranges if any and that size > 0
                        if ((xMinConfigured && m1 < xAxisConfig.min) ||
                            (xMaxConfigured && m1 > xAxisConfig.max) ||
                            (yMinConfigured && m2 < yAxisConfig.min) ||
                            (yMaxConfigured && m2 > yAxisConfig.max) ||
                            m3 <= 0) {
                            return;
                        }                        

                        self.state.indexVsMetaIndex[dataForJq.length] = i;

                        var color = SERIES_COLORS[colorIndex % SERIES_COLORS.length];
                        var getBubbleColorMeasure = self.options.WidgetDefinition.ConfigJson.ModelDefinition.BubbleColorMeasures;
                        var getRegularMeasures = self.state.meta.filter(function(item) {
                            return item.MeasureId;
                          });

                        var dynamicIndex = 4; // Default index for accessing aRow[4]

                        if (getBubbleColorMeasure && getBubbleColorMeasure.length > 0) {
                            var bubbleMeasureId = getBubbleColorMeasure[0].Id;

                            // Find the index of the object with matching Id in getRegularMeasures
                            var regularMeasureIndex = getRegularMeasures.findIndex(function (measure) {
                                return measure.MeasureId === bubbleMeasureId;
                            });

                            if (regularMeasureIndex !== -1) {
                                dynamicIndex = regularMeasureIndex + 1; // Adjust the index to be dynamic
                            }

                            var getColor = aRow ? aRow[dynamicIndex][1] : null;
                            var bgColorRgb = null;
                            var fgColorRgb = null;
                            if (getColor) {
                                var bgColorCode = getColor.bg ? getColor.bg : null;
                                var fgColorCode = getColor.fg ? getColor.fg : null;
                                bgColorRgb = bgColorCode ? util.getConditionalFormatBgColor(bgColorCode) : null;
                                fgColorRgb = fgColorCode ? util.getConditionalFormatBgColor(fgColorCode) : null;
                            }
                            seriesForegroundColors.push(fgColorRgb);
                        }
            
                        if (bgColorRgb) {
                            seriesBackgroundColors.push(bgColorRgb);
                        } else {
                            seriesBackgroundColors.push(color);
                            colorIndex++;
                        }

                        dataForJq.push([m1, m2, m3, label]);                        
                    });                    
                    
                    // Avoiding Overlapping Issue, by Sorting the data in descending order of size measure
                    //  to ensure that bigger sized bubbles are plotted first followed by smaller sized bubbles
                    if (sizeMeasure) {
                        // Create a mapping of data points to their background and foreground colors
                        var colorMapping = dataForJq.map(function (dataPoint, index) {
                            return {
                                dataPoint: dataPoint,
                                backgroundColor: seriesBackgroundColors[index],
                                foregroundColor: seriesForegroundColors[index]
                            };
                        });

                        dataForJq.sort(function (a, b) { return a[MEASURE_INDEX.SIZE] < b[MEASURE_INDEX.SIZE] ? 1 : a[MEASURE_INDEX.SIZE] > b[MEASURE_INDEX.SIZE] ? -1 : 0; }); 

                        // Reorder seriesBackgroundColors and seriesForegroundColors based on the new order of dataForJq
                        var sortedBackgroundColors = [];
                        var sortedForegroundColors = [];

                        // For each sorted data point, find the corresponding colors from the mapping
                        dataForJq.forEach(function (sortedDataPoint) {
                            var match = colorMapping.find(function (map) {
                                return map.dataPoint[MEASURE_INDEX.LABEL] === sortedDataPoint[MEASURE_INDEX.LABEL]; // Assuming index 3 is the unique label
                            });
                            if (match) {
                                sortedBackgroundColors.push(match.backgroundColor);
                                sortedForegroundColors.push(match.foregroundColor);
                            }
                        });

                        // Reassign the sorted colors back to the original arrays
                        seriesBackgroundColors = sortedBackgroundColors;
                        seriesForegroundColors = sortedForegroundColors;

                        //  Update the indexVsMetaIndex Map after dataForJq is sorted.
                        var metaDimValues = self.state.meta[0].DimensionValues;
                        $.each(dataForJq, function (index, aDataVal) {
                            var metaIndex = _.findIndex(metaDimValues, function (aMetaVal) { return aMetaVal.DisplayName === aDataVal[MEASURE_INDEX.LABEL]; });
                            self.state.indexVsMetaIndex[index] = metaIndex;
                        });
                    }                    

                    if (dataForJq.length === 0) {
                        showMessage(util.getTranslatedString(util.translations.BCMNoDataInSelRange), self.element, util.MESSAGE_TYPE_WARNING);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    var jqplotOptions = {
                        animate: false,
                        animateReplot: false,
                        title: (sizeMeasure) ? util.getTranslatedString(util.translations.BCLBubbleSize, bco.sizeLabel) : "",
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
                            rendererOptions: {
                                bubbleAlpha: bco.Alpha,
                                highlightAlpha: bco.HighlightAlpha,
                                bubbleGradients: false,
                                varyBubbleColors: bco.VaryColors,
                                autoscaleBubbles: (sizeMeasure) ? bco.autoscaleBubbles : false,
                                autoscalePointsFactor: -0.07, //[-.07, 0.2]
                                autoscaleMultiplier: bubbleScaleFactor,
                                showLabels: bco.ShowName,
                                clipOverflows: bco.clipDisplayNameOverflow,
                                foregroundColors: seriesForegroundColors,
                            },
                            shadow: false,
                            lineWidth: 3,
                            useNegativeColors: false,
                            //Explicitly disabling the pointLabels.
                            //jqplot by default picks up all the default plugins with default options.
                            pointLabels: {
                                show: false
                            }
                        },
                        series: [
                            {
                                isDragable: false,
                                showHighlight: true
                            }
                        ],
                        seriesColors: seriesBackgroundColors,
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: xAxisConfig,
                            yaxis: yAxisConfig
                        },
                        highlighter: {
                            show: bco.highlightMouseOver,
                            showMarker: false,
                            tooltipLocation: 'ne',
                            tooltipOffset: -1,           
                            tooltipContentEditor: self._getToolTipFn()
                        },
                        grid: {
                            background: bco.backgroundColor,
                            gridLineColor: bco.gridLineColor,
                            borderColor: bco.borderColor,
                            shadow: false
                        },
                        cursor:{zoom:true},
                        canvasOverlay: canvasOverlayOptions
                    };
                    
                    try {
                        //console.log("BCDEBUG::Inside render:: Rendered Data:: ", dataForJq);
                        self.state.chart = $.jqplot(divId, [dataForJq], jqplotOptions);
                        self._preventXTicksOverlap();
                    } catch (exception) {
                        showMessage(exception.message, self.element, util.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR);
                        console.log(exception);
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    showMessage(util.getTranslatedString(util.translations.BCMNoDataForSelFilter), self.element, util.MESSAGE_TYPE_WARNING);
                }
            },

            /**
             * Quadrant lines and diagonals are plotted using canvasoverlay.
             * @returns the jqplot options related to canvas overlay plugin.
             * @private
             */
            _getCanvasOverlayOptions: function (xMeasure, yMeasure) {
                var self = this;
                var options = self.rOptions;
                var bco = options.BubblechartOptions;
                var meta = self.state.meta;
                var data = self.state.data;
                var lines = [];
                var canvasOverlayOptions = {
                    show: false
                };
                if (!xMeasure.ShowMidLine && !yMeasure.ShowMidLine && !bco.ShowForwardDiagonal && !bco.ShowBackDiagonal) {
                    return canvasOverlayOptions;
                }

                canvasOverlayOptions.show = true;
                canvasOverlayOptions.bellowSeries = true;

                var xMin = xMeasure.Min;
                var xMax = xMeasure.Max;
                var yMin = yMeasure.Min;
                var yMax = yMeasure.Max;
                //xMidLine
                if (xMeasure.ShowMidLine) {
                    lines.push({
                        verticalLine: {
                            name: 'xMid',
                            drawMid: true,
                            // x: (xMin + xMax)/2,
                            yOffset: 0,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            color: bco.gridLineColor,
                            shadow: false,
                            showTooltip: false
                        }
                    });
                }

                //yMidLine
                if (yMeasure.ShowMidLine) {
                    lines.push({
                        horizontalLine: {
                            name: 'yMid',
                            drawMid: true,
                            //y: (yMin + yMax)/2,
                            xOffset: 0,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            color: bco.gridLineColor,
                            shadow: false,
                            showTooltip: false
                        }
                    });
                }

                //forwardDiagonal
                if (bco.ShowForwardDiagonal) {
                    lines.push({
                        line: {
                            name: 'forwardDiagonal',
                            /*start: [xMin, yMin],
                             stop: [xMax, yMax],*/
                            diagonal: "forward",
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            color: bco.gridLineColor,
                            shadow: false,
                            showTooltip: false
                        }
                    });
                }

                //backDiagonal
                if (bco.ShowBackDiagonal) {
                    lines.push({
                        line: {
                            name: 'backDiagonal',
                            start: [xMax, yMin],
                            stop: [xMin, yMax],
                            diagonal: "back",
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            color: bco.gridLineColor,
                            shadow: false,
                            showTooltip: false
                        }
                    });
                }

                canvasOverlayOptions.objects = lines;
                return canvasOverlayOptions;
            }

I want to show the proper quadrant where exactly bubble lies in which quadrants after zooming also.
Any logic for this?
